# Backbone.js - weird issue when removing a model from a tweet.

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm having some problems with backbone.js. while all my code works, I do get an exception: 
`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '(e=this.models[c]).cid')`.

The exceptions occurs when the amount of models exceed a limit, and I call self.remove() in the collection.

```
var Column = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(col) {
        var view = new ColumnView({
            id: "column_" + col.id,
            column: col
        });

        view.render();
    },

    comparator: function(tweet) {
        return tweet.get('created_at_time');
    },

    clean: function() {
        var self        = this;
        var total       = this.models.length;
        var threshold   = (total - window.config.threshold) - 1;

        if(threshold > 0) {
            console.log("Removing if tweet is older then " + threshold);
            this.models.forEach(function(tweet, index) {
                if(index < threshold) {
                    self.remove(tweet);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Does anyone know what's going on? The error occurs on safari.

Comment: **1.** Can you indicate in which exactly line of your code the error is launched?, **2.** Would be helpful if you try to create a minimal version of your code that reproduce the issue and upload it to [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), **3.** I'm not sure if is a good idea to `remove` elements from one Array while you `iterate` over it.

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, it is caused by the fact you remove models while iterating over the list of models.

Try

```
if (threshold > 0) {

    var removed = [];
    this.models.forEach(function (tweet, index) {
        if (index < threshold) {
            removed.push(tweet);
        }
    });
    this.remove(removed);
}
```

or a variant suggested by @mu

```
if (threshold > 0) {

    var removed =  this.filter(function(model, index) {
            return index < threshold;
    });
    this.remove(removed);
}
```

or maybe simpler in your case

```
if (threshold > 0) {
    this.remove(this.models.slice(0, threshold));
}
```